# Trying to add properties to application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

I created a new maven project. But after I try to add things to the application.properties file, my pom.xml file brokes. There is no error when I have empty properties file, but when I add even a comment, my pom shows this error.

[image]

I cant add my database configuration because of this. This error doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: What happends if you run ```mvn resources:resources``` from the command line?

Comment: You need to provide more details, not just a photo with a message which occupies half of your pom... There's no code visible and some parts are censoured

Comment: I dont have mvn installed. I used spring initializr for making that project.